# Possibility to make code smaller

Tags: php

Is there any way to make my code smaller? I mean it's I bet there is a way to make it smaller but I don't know, I have the following code full of `if`:

```
if($CType != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CType </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CNr != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CNr </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CValFrom != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CValFrom </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CValUntil != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CValUntil </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CLTCCNr != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CLTCCNr </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CLTCCTime != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CLTCCTime </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CIOEntryOff != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CIOEntryOff </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CIOExitOff != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CIOExitOff </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CICoded != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CICoded </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CCodingDate != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CCodingDate </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CPrice != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CPrice </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CPricePyed != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CPricePyed </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CDeposit != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CDeposit </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CDepositPayed != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CDepositPayed </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CLastCCode != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CLastCCode </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CLastLPlate != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CLastLPlate </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CIOOffNextUse != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CIOOffNextUse </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CLastEntryTime != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CLastEntryTime </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CLastExitTime != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CLastExitTime </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
            if($CLastPTime != NULL)
                    {
                        echo '<th align="right">CLastPTime </th>';
                    }else{

                    }
```

How can I make it short is there a way of doing it? It should work the same way.

Comment: This should really be posted to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: Oh didn't know that, I'll post there thanks...

Comment: Give us a link :) just to challenge who can make it smaller

Comment: if you just want to make it smaller , then remove all elses u have wrote , coz you are doing nothing in else part! u l save 18 lines :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.

One of them:

```
$tableHeaders = [
  ['variable' => 'CType', 'title' => 'Tipo'],
  ['variable' => 'CNr', 'title' => 'Nr.'],
  ...
];

foreach($tableHeaders as $tableHeader) : 
  $variable = $tableHeader['variable'];
  if (!isset($$variable) OR is_null($$variable)) continue;
?>
  <th align="right"><?= $tableHeader['title']; ?></th>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
```

But recommended way is just to use normal template engine and let it to render dataset itself